# Is the value of steady_clock::now from multiple threads consistent with memory order?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, relaxed-atomics

Within one thread, `steady_clock::now()` is guaranteed to return monotonically increasing values. How does this interact with memory ordering and reads observed by multiple threads?

```
atomic<int> arg{0};
steady_clock::time_point a, b, c, d;
int e;
thread t1([&](){
    a = steady_clock::now();
    arg.store(1, memory_order_release);
    b = steady_clock::now();
});
thread t2([&](){
    c = steady_clock::now();
    e = arg.load(memory_order_acquire);
    d = steady_clock::now();
});
t1.join();
t2.join()
assert(a <= b);
assert(c <= d);
```

Here's the important bit:

```
if (e) {
    assert(a <= d);
} else {
    assert(c <= b);
}
```

Can these assert ever fail? Or have I misunderstood something about acquire release memory order?

What follows is mostly an explanation and elaboration of my code example.

Thread `t1` writes to the atomic `arg`. It also records the current time before and after the write in `a` and `b` respectively. `steady_clock` guarantees that `a <= b`.

Thread `t2` reads from the atomic `arg` and saves the value read in `e`. It also records the current time before and after the read in `c` and `d` respectively. `steady_clock` guarantees that `c <= d`.

Both threads are then joined. At this point `e` could be `0` or `1`.

If `e` is `0`, then `t2` read the value before `t1` wrote it. **Does this also imply that `c = now()` in `t2` happened before `b = now()` in `t1`?**

If `e` is `1` then `t1` wrote the value before `t2` read it. **Does this also imply that `a = now()` in `t1` happened before `d = now()` in `t2`?**

---

Here are some existing questions that don't answer what I'm asking:

[Is there any std::chrono thread safety guarantee even with multicore context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894504/is-there-any-stdchrono-thread-safety-guarantee-even-with-multicore-context)

I'm not asking whether `now()` is thread-safe. I know it is.

[Is steady_clock monotonic across threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930541/is-steady-clock-monotonic-across-threads)

This one is much closer, but that example uses `mutex`. Can I make the same assumptions about memory orderings weaker than `seq_cst`?

Comment: Please edit your original question if you want to clarify that your question is not a duplicate. Also, you can ping the users who closed your question, and they'll be happy to reevaluate. I see you've deleted your original question, but in the future it's better to just edit the original instead of posting a new question.

Comment: The private feedback thing at the top said the question is closed and I should open a new one if it really isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that is what the banner says.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the banner message is misleading, and you *are* supposed to edit the original question if possible (as you did in this case). I'm sorry the banner message is confusing in that regard.

Comment: I don't see any connection between a chrono clock methods and memory ordering. please explain why do you think there's a connection? `system_clock::now` doesn't synchronize anything.

Comment: Where do I mention `system_clock`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unfortunately incomplete. Acquire and release memory orders prevent reordering in one direction only. Consider `t1`:

```
a = steady_clock::now();
arg.store(1, memory_order_release);
b = steady_clock::now();
```

`a` indeed gets assigned before `arg.store`. But the compiler is free to reorder the assignment to `b` to happen before as well.

Similarly, in `t2`:

```
c = steady_clock::now();
e = arg.load(memory_order_acquire);
d = steady_clock::now();
```

`d` indeed gets assigned after `arg.load`. But the compiler is free to reorder the assignment to `c` to happen after as well.

**Therefore `assert(c <= b)` may fail.**

There is however one caveat. This is only true if `steady_clock::now()` is known to have no observable effects. However, on platforms where I have looked at its implementation, this results in a call to some opaque library function. Compilers must assume that such calls could have observable effects (such as modifying a volatile variable or terminating the program), and therefore will not reorder the calls.

The question would be valid if the important asserts consisted solely of

```
if (e) { assert (a <= d); }
```

or if both memory orders were `acq_rel` or `seq_cst`.

So, given that either the memory orders are corrected or the assert is checked only when `e != 0`, I can be sure that the relevant calls to `steady_clock::now()` actually happen in the correct order, even across threads.

**But does this also imply that the values returned are consistent with that order across both `t1` and `t2`, rather than just within `t1` and `t2` in isolation?**

I don't know, which is why I won't accept this answer.